# Configure GIT lab pipiline

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I want to configure my pipeline in such a way that the stages are picked as per passing param. For instance I have 3 scenarios, Scenario 1, Scenario 2 and Scenario 3. All 3 scenario have different stages like

```
Scenario 1 have following stages
stages:
  - deploy
  - test
  - job2


Scenario 2 have following stages
stages:
  - deploy
  - test
  - regression


Scenario 3 have following stages
 stages:
  - deploy
  - test
```

I want to configure my yml like that, depends on any param or condition these pipeline get executed.

```
Like 
 if(true){ 
   Scenario 1
}else if {
  Scenario 2
 }.....
```

I dont want to use child pipeline.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to define pipelines like that in Gitlab. Although you can `include` templates or jobs into your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, at runtime it is still one pipeline.

You can get the same result (only running some jobs based on whatever conditions you need) using the `rules` keyword on jobs. So for example, your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file might look like this:

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - test
  - regression

Scenario 1 Deploy Job:
  stage: deploy
  when: never
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == main && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == trigger"
      when: always
      start_in: 3 hours
    - if: "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == schedules"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

Scenario 1 Test Job:
   ...
```

The `rules` keyword lets you define conditions to decide when a job is added to a running pipeline or not. If a job has multiple `if`'s (like the "Scenario 1 Deploy Job"), they're treated as ORs (if this OR that), but multiple conditions inline can use && or ||.

So to sum up, pipelines can only have one set of stages, projects can only have one pipeline definition, but you can control when you want each job to run or not.